# Columnwise filter with dropdown in asp.net gridview using DataTable.js

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, datatables

DataTable.js provides [Columnwise Search with Dropdown](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) as shown here.

I have made exact demo here [using HTML,CSS,JS only](https://plnkr.co/edit/a0kpcm41OOL79VHuPSIK?p=info) which also works fine.

Now, In my asp.net webforms project I have integrated `DataTable.js` that works perfectly fine.

How have I done it? here it is,

***gridview.aspx***

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">

    <link href="Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.jqueryui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
   </asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="gvdatatable" AutoGenerateColumns="true" OnPreRender="GridView1_PreRender"></asp:GridView>


<script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').DataTable({
                 initComplete: function () {
                     this.api().columns().every(function () {
                         var column = this;
                         var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                             .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                             .on('change', function () {
                                 var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                     $(this).val()
                                 );

                                 column
                                     .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                                     .draw();
                             });

                         column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                             select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                         });
                     });
                 }
             });
         });
        </script>
</asp:Content>
```

***gridview.aspx.cs***

```
protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
                GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
                GridView1.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
            }

        }
```

Everything works fine. Just the problem is it doesn't show dropdown with values at bottom. Is there something I'm missing?

How to do it?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

***Extra Notes:***

Recently figure out that, in DataTable example, it has

```
  <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

when I check console, gridview's `<tfoot>` is empty. I think there some magic is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Inside

```
<asp:GridView />
```

you need

```
showfooter="true"
```